# Need to understand usage of "so as much" here

Tags: usage

I was reading "The stranger" in which a person is guilty of a murder. The prosecutor asks "Has he **so much as** expressed any remorse?"

I understand that he is trying to ask if he has expressed any remorse till this time. I am not used to the sentence used above and trying to understand the usage of "so much as" here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functional phrase here is:

> so much as

Which is used to indicate a very minimal level of effort, for example:

> This is the laziest example of plagiarism I've ever seen, the student didn't so much as change a single word from the original source.

You can generally replace the phrase "so much as" with the word "even"

In your case:

> Has he even expressed any remorse?

The "as" is being used in the comparative sense, like in the phrase:

> Did he do as well as Frank?

To compare the actions of the person in question with the stated standard.

Comment: @SunMan  Hi and did you know that you could also upvote this answer? You accepted it as helpful, but you can also reward mstorkson by clicking on the up arrow. It's the way we say 'thank you' on Stack Exchange. I am new here too and just passing along what I've learned.